# Why can $y=0$ be considered the asymptote of $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, asymptotics

Why can $y=0$ be considered the asymptote of $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ when the two graphs don't get any closer when $x$ approaches infinity? Because isn't the asymptote something that a graph will touch and stay on once the graph reaches infinity? And yet, in $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$, the size of $x$ has no effect on the graph's proximity to the asymptote. It just keeps fluctuating around $y=0$! So that suggests that the graph won't touch and stay on the asymptote at infinity? And if it doesn't, how can $y=0$ still be considered the asymptote of $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: "asymptote" simply means a line such that the distance between the line and the graph tends to zero. We don't care about fluctuations.

Comment: "The size of x has no effect on the graph's proximity to the asymptote."  Not so.

Comment: @Wojowu According to Wikipedia (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote), "Some sources include the requirement [in the definition of "asymptote"] that the curve may not cross the line infinitely often, but this is unusual for modern authors." A literal reading of the word's etymology would also support this requirement, so Ethan Chen is more justified than he might think. (In the context of rational functions, of course, the extra stipulation makes no difference.)

Answer (score 7):

There are several misconceptions in your post.

$$\frac{\sin x}{x}$$ does get closer and closer to $0$ when $x$ increases. In fact,

$$\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\le\frac1x$$ and the RHS clearly tends to $0$.

"... isn't the asymptote something that a graph will touch and stay on ...": no, quite often an asymptote doesn't touch the curve. It just needs to come arbitrarily close. In the case at hand, it crosses it infinitely often, but this does not matter.

Answer (score 4):

I have already [written to you about this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858356/why-can-a-graph-pass-through-its-horizontal-asymptote). Look at the graph of your function:

[image]

Don't you agree that, as we move to the right, the graph gets closer to $0$? To be more precise, if we fix a number $\varepsilon>0$, then, if $M$ is large enough, the graph of the restriction of $f$ to $[M,+\infty)$ is between the lines $y=\varepsilon$ and $y=-\varepsilon$. That's what it means that the line $y=0$ is an asymptote of the graph of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of an [horizontal asymptote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Horizontal_asymptotes) is that 
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = c.$$

Which is exactly the case here with $c=0$.

**In no way the definition of an asymptote implies that the function is supposed to stay on the same side of the asymptote for $x$ large enough.**

Comment: So when x gets to infinity $sin(x)/x$ becomes 0? How so? Can you please explain this in the terms of someone who hasn't learnt calculus yet? Thanks.

Comment: Using simple words: $\sin x$ is bounded by $1$. If you divide $1$ by a large number you get a number close to $0$.

Comment: Ah right, I forgot about that. But how do we know sinx will output 1 when x=infinity?

Comment: It will not output $1$... It will output something that is less or equal to $1$ which is even better!

Answer (score 1):

> f(x)=sinx/x, the size of x has no effect on the graph's proximity to the asymptote.

Yes it does:
$$\text{max}_{x>x_0}\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}-0\right|\leq \frac{1}{x_0}$$