# Is $y=0$ a horizontal asymptote for $f(x)=0$?

Tags: calculus

It seems (see [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858356), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860434)) that the formal definition of a horizontal asymptote is that the function simply needs to get "arbitrarily close" to the asymptote.

So would it be the case that $y=0$ be a horizontal asymptote for $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the case.

Formally, we would define a line $y=c$ to be a [horizontal asymptote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Horizontal_asymptotes) of $y=f(x)$ if either $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=c$ or $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=c$.

In this case, we have $f(x)=0$ and $c=0$. Then, the limits become $\lim_{x\to\infty}0=0$ or $\lim_{x\to-\infty}0=0$. These statements are trivially true (though if we wanted we could use epsilon-delta to rigorously prove it).